# gfortran - file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, ld, gfortran

I couldn't find a working answer for my problem on any of the similar questions asked so I'm asking again.

My computer is Mac OSX 10.8 Mountain Lion. I'm trying to build a Fortran program using gfortran and I get to my error like so:

```
gfortran-mp-4.7 -O2 -c constants.f90
gfortran-mp-4.7 -O2 -c utils.F90
...(more source files)
ar -r libcamb.a constants.o utils.o ...(more source files)
/opt/local/bin/ranlib: file: libcamb.a(constants.o) has no symbols
gfortran-mp-4.7 -DMATRIX_SINGLE -O2 -I../camb -I../multinest -DDR71RG -DNOWMAP -c utils.F90
gfortran-mp-4.7 -DMATRIX_SINGLE -O2 -I../camb -I../multinest -DDR71RG -DNOWMAP -c ParamNames.f90
gfortran-mp-4.7 -DMATRIX_SINGLE -O2 -I../camb -I../multinest -DDR71RG -DNOWMAP -c Matrix_utils.F90
gfortran-mp-4.7 -DMATRIX_SINGLE -O2 -I../camb -I../multinest -DDR71RG -DNOWMAP -c settings.f90
gfortran-mp-4.7 -DMATRIX_SINGLE -O2 -I../camb -I../multinest -DDR71RG -DNOWMAP -c GetDist.f90
gfortran-mp-4.7 -o ../getdist utils.o ParamNames.o Matrix_utils.o settings.o GetDist.o -L../camb -lcamb -llapack -latlas -Wl,-framework -Wl,accelerate -L/opt/local/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -DMATRIX_SINGLE -O2 -I../camb -I ../multinest -DDR71RG -DNOWMAP 
ld: warning: ignoring file ../camb/libcamb.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): ../camb/libcamb.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
<<long list of undefined functions that are defined in the library that was ignored>>
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

`arch` returns i386 and `uname -a` shows x86_64 at the end.

I've just built the library and using the same compiler, so why does it say that it's ignoring it because it's the wrong architecture?